# Using Bob SQL Access Toolkit with pgx's conneciton pool implementation

Tags: go, pgx, bob

I'm evaluating [`Bob SQL Access Toolkit`](https://bob.stephenafamo.com/) for a new project. I would like to also use the [`pgx`](https://github.com/jackc/pgx) connection pool implementation.

This is what I have so far in order to integrate the libraries (error handling removed):

```golang
ctx := context.Background()
pool, err := pgxpool.New(context.Background(), os.Getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
// error handling
defer pool.Close()
conn, _ := pool.Acquire(ctx)
defer conn.Release()
query := psql.Select(sm.From("categories"), sm.Where(psql.S("id").EQ(psql.Arg(id)))) // id uuid.UUID and passed as argument to the function
result, err := bob.One(ctx, BOB_EXECUTOR?, query, scan.StructMapper[model.Category]())
```

Problem I'm facing is that `Bob` requires an [*executor*](https://bob.stephenafamo.com/docs/sql-executor/types), and that's where I'm not entirely sure how the integration between those two technologies could work.

Any pointers with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`stdlib.OpenDBPool()`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgx/v5/stdlib#OpenDBFromPool) function for this, which creates a new `*sql.DB` instance from a given pool.

To make this `*sql.DB` conform to [`bob.Executor` interface](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/stephenafamo/bob#Executor), wrap it in a [`bob.NewDB()`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/stephenafamo/bob#NewDB):

```golang
db := bob.NewDB(stdlib.OpenDBFromPool(indexCrawler.pgxPool))
defer func() { _ = db.Close() }()
```

Then simply pass this `db` to Bob's autogenerated code.